# AngularJS ng-repeat is not responding

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head><title> angular js </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body  ng-app="myApp">


<div ng-controller="personCtrl" >
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
       <thead>
       <tr>
          <th> Artist </th>
          <th> Title </th>
          <th> Genra </th>
          <th> Ratings </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="song in songs">
             <td>{{ songs.Artist }}</td>
             <td>{{ songs.Title }}</td>
             <td>{{ songs.Genre }}</td>
             <td>{{ songs.Ratings }}</td>
           </tr> 
      </tbody>  

   </table>
                 </div>
             </div>
              </div>
            </div>


<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {


 var songs =     [{Artist:"Kamikazee",Title:"Chicksilog",Genre:"Punk",Ratings:7},
           {Artist:"Hale",Title:"Bakit pa",Genre:"Alternative",Ratings:5},
           ];

$scope.song = songs;

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

good day, i just want to ask for a solution or maybe someone can figure out what is wrong with my Codes. here is the problem, i want to display a list of songs in a table, as you can see  i put the list in a variable called "song".  and  used angular controller to make it happen And im pretty sure that my controller "personCtrl" is connected to the View html since i run some test  and everything works fine. but then when i  use ng-repeat method for displaying the list in the table nothing is happening in my View table, the problem starts there. thank you hoping for a reply :)

Comment: In your controller, replace `$scope.song = songs` by `$scope.songs=songs`. In your view, change the interpollation for `{{songs.something}}` to `{{song.something}}`.

Comment: you just need to you `{{song.whatever}}` not `songs`

Comment: Omg what a rookie mistake hihih thank you guys for the fast reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="song in songs">
             <td>{{ song.Artist }}</td>
             <td>{{ song.Title }}</td>
             <td>{{ song.Genre }}</td>
             <td>{{ song.Ratings }}</td>
           </tr>
```

song / songs :)